# PT1000 temperature value with decimal point

Tags: plc

I have connected PT1000 to my WAGO 750-880 PLC and the input value is in hundreds, that is instead of 34.1C it shows 341C. I tried to divide the input by 10 but then output becomes only 34 without decimal point.
How can I get the temperature value with decimal point? Should I divide by 10 and use a specific type for the output (now I use output:REAL)?
Thank you.

Comment: The "type for the output" doesn't really matter when your  division by 10 is done using integers. Use floats throughout. If that doesn't work, show your code.

Comment: "when your division by 10 is done using integers" here it is!! After reading this, I tried to divide by 10.0 instead of 10 and it works now. Thank you very much, Jongware!

Comment: An important question to ask is *why* does it matter?  Is `341` not equivalently useful to `34.1`?  A single division can eat up as much processing time as hundreds of loads/stores/adds/etc.  As a general rule, if you can reformulate your logic to avoid the division then you probably should, especially if your scan time is important.